LAST_INSERT_ID MySQL
I have 3 tables - users, purchases and users_purchases. To connect purchases and users, we need an id from the purchase table, as well as an id from the users table. In order to find out the generated id in MySQL, the only solution is to use the LAST_INSERT_ID function. Let's say we have code that looks like this:
INSERT INTO purchases VALUES(...);

INSERT INTO purchases_users(id_user, id_purchase) VALUES(1, LAST_INSERT_ID())`

But what if, at the time of adding a purchase row, a new user is added, and after that the LAST_INSERT_ID function is called. Will there be a user ID or purchase ID there?
Perhaps it would not hurt me to go deeper into sql theories, but still I did not find a specific answer with a similar example

LAST_INSERT_ID() should be isolated to the single connection: if ANOTHER, different connection inserts a new user, your session won't see it by calling that function.

@matteo-tassinari Will this work if I use sessions rather than connections?

I am not sure what you mean when you say to "use sessions rather than connections". As far as I know, in the context of MySQL, a connection "is" a session; when you disconnect and reconnect, a new session begins.

I don’t know for sure if this exists in MySQL, but in Postgres there are the concepts of pool and connection, so I meant pool. There may be several of these simultaneous pools in my application and there is only one connection

MySQL doesn't have that AFAIK. PHP servers have the option to use shared connections, but it's not the default.

So unless you do something special, the caveats in the linked question should be all you have to worry about.

note that last_insert_id only works with auto_increment; if you are setting the id some other way, it will not return it
